# Use color palette in Sakura

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, sakura

I am using Sakura as my terminal emulator and would like to use the Solarized Dark color scheme. My terminal is currently black with white font for everything- there is no color differentiation between directories, files, hostnames etc.

**What I've tried:**

In `~/.config/sakura/sakura.conf` I have the line

`palette=solarized_dark`

which doesn't seem to have any effect. I also tried changing the lines

`colorset1_fore=rgb(255,255,255)`

and

`colorset1_back=rgba(0,0,0,1)`

these change the text and background colors but I don't know how to make the terminal use more than 2 colors.

I have also tried changing colors in the GUI but this had the same effects as sakura.conf:

*RightClick>Options>More>Set Palette>Solarized Dark*     had no effect.

*RightClick>Options>Select Colors*    let me pick one text color and one background color from the default

**Other Notes:**

I am running Arch Linux, LightDM, Awesome and X.

I created a .Xresources file to try to change colors but Sakura doesn't seem to use that-tell me if I am wrong about this.

There is a solarized-dark-themes package in the AUR, but shouldn't that already be included in Sakura?